# Changing Stripe Button to a Custom Button Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stripe-payments

I have a stripe button and want to add my custom class. I found that you can manually create the CSS for it and it will work, although, I want to keep all the buttons on my site consistent by using my custom class.

Whatever I try I cannot remove the default button

```
<form action="/update-the-card" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}"
    data-name="My site"
    data-panel-label="Update Card"
    data-label="Update Card"
    data-allow-remember-me=false
    data-locale="auto">
    </script>
</form>
```

My class is '`button fstyle1 thin`' that id like on it

I've tried this but does not work.

```
 $('button.stripe-button-el').removeAttr('style').addClass('button fstyle1 thin')
```

Comment: Does $('button.stripe-button-el')  return a button?   Did you mean to do .stripe-button instead?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath yes, it returns that button.. which is strange. Thats how other people grabbed it

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. All you need to do is add your own custom submit button and just hide the one stripe provides you with. Very easy.

```
<form action="/update-the-card" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}"
        data-amount="44040"
        data-name="nameeee"
        data-description="descriptionnn"
        data-locale="auto">
    </script>
    <script>
        // Hide default stripe button, be careful there if you
        // have more than 1 button of that class
        document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = 'none';
    </script>
    <button type="submit" class="button green fsize-16 f-weight-400">Purchase Here!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is your class (button fstyle1 thin) level is lower then `.stripe-button-el`

Try add `!important` in you css.

or add more css combinators like: `.a .b .c form .fstyle1`

Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe your `.button.stripe-button-el` element is not exist in the `DOM` at the time of binding(means created dynamically).

So you can bind your event handler to a higher element `$(document)`.

Try to use `$(document)` here...

```
$(document).find("button.stripe-button-el").removeAttr("style").addClass("button fstyle1 thin");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @victory said, **the easier solution is to hide the button given by stripe** by this line :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = 'none';
```

**If you have multiple stripe buttons on one page**, this will do the job :

```
<script>
  var all_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el");
  for (var i = 0; i < all_buttons.length; i++) {
    all_buttons[i].style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).find("button.stripe-button-el").removeAttr("style").addClass("'button fstyle1 thin'");
$(".stripe-button-el").find("span").remove();
$(".stripe-button-el").html("Proceed to pay");
```